# How to make a textbox accept only float values

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a windows form . In that there is a textbox . I want that textbox to accept only float values.

Comment: `NumericUpDown` control?

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in `textbox_PreviewTextInput` event:

```
private void txtBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e) 
{ 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$"); 
e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // allows 0-9, backspace, and decimal
        if (((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 46))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        // checks to make sure only 1 decimal is allowed
        if (e.KeyChar == 46)
        {
            if ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) != -1)
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two time to check the value, I think.

(1): KeyPress Event Handler (it's occured when key press)

(2): Validating Event Handler (it's occured when lost focus)

Sample code is below:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.')
        {
            if (this.Text.IndexOf(".") >= 0 || this.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != '\b')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        float value;
        if (!float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value)) { textBox1.Text = ""; }
    }
```

Comment: The \B metacharacter is used to find a match not at the beginning or end of a word.

If no match is found, it returns null.

Comment: but if we put 2 dots , it is taking like  " 25..3." and it is also not taking f character