# Only accept numerics characters in textbox

Tags: textbox, character, numeric

I try to do a things very easy but it doesn't works...

I want my textbox accepts only numerics characters. I found a lot of parts of code on internet but none working...

I try this code for example :

```
    private void TxtNumPoste_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
            (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

TxtNumPoste is the name of my TextBox.

Is a person sees an error ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129605/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-float-values

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: There isn't error but it doesn't works. I can enter some letters in my textbox and normally with this code I can only write numerics characters, is it right ?